# vue: how to filter data from array

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am new with Vue and I am using API to show data, here in my code when click is performed to category it saves that name of category and redirects user to another page called `category.vue`, my problem is after redirecting user I want now to show questions with that category name that been received only (as filter), is there a way to do it?

```html
  
  /* this is how i saved data to transfer to category page */
  
  <div class="category" v-for="(categoryy,index) in category(question1)" :key="index">
   <router-link :to="`/category/${category(question1)}`"> {{ categoryy }} </router-link>
    
       </div>
```

category.vue

```html
<template>
  
    <div class="vw">
   <p> related question of </p>
    
  <p>{{ this.$route.params.cat }}</p> /* category name i sent appears here */
       
     <ul class="container-question" v-for="(question1,index) in questions" :key="index"  

  >
/* THE PROBLEM : it shows all questions without filtering */
  
     {{question1.question}}
         </ul>
    </div>
 
</template>
<script>
export default {
    
    props:
{
    question1: Object
},
data(){
    return{
questions: []
    }
    


},
computed:{
    category(){
        let category = this.$route.params.cat;
        return category
    }
},
mounted: function(){
fetch('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=9&difficulty=medium&type=multiple',{
  method: 'get'
})
.then((response) => {
  return response.json()
})
.then((jsonData) => {
  this.questions = jsonData.results
})
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first get all the categories with this route https://opentdb.com/api_category.php
As i suspect you already have done on the first vue page.

Then as you do, you pass the id of the category as a route param.

The only thing you seem to miss here is that you have hardcoded the category id 9 in your mounted fetch.

You would want to change this to:

```
fetch(`https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=${this.category}&difficulty=medium&type=multiple`,{
  method: 'get'
})
```

This way uses the computed property you created above from the router param from the previous page.

Comment: this will show me only the category that i clicked , what i want is to show all questions related to the category i clicked

Comment: What do you mean? This will show you all questions related to the category you clicked. Example, this.category = 9; - https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=9&difficulty=medium&type=multiple
Does this list not represent the data you want?

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass the route param not in a computed property, but directly on the mounted hook,

```js
export default {
  mounted() {
    fetch(
      `https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=${this.$route.params.cat}&difficulty=medium&type=multiple`,
      {
        method: "get",
      }
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((jsonData) => (this.questions = jsonData.results));
  },
};
```

Comment: this will show me only the category that i clicked , what i want is to show all questions related to the category i clicked